# PHP,MySql : How to know which table was used

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this SQL line:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, url, description, champion, video_length, datemade FROM our_videos UNION SELECT id, title, url, description, champion, video_length, datemade FROM combo_videos ORDER BY datemade DESC LIMIT 10";
```

And to work further I need to know which table was used in query, was it `our_vidoes` or was it `combo_videos`, both tables looks the same but have different data in it, so how do I check that?

Comment: you use both, can you explain wath you try to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Mysql, you can do the following :

> select "something" as columnName;

You can modify your query like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, url, description, champion, video_length, datemade, "our_videos" as tableName FROM our_videos UNION SELECT id, title, url, description, champion, video_length, datemade, "our_videos" as tableName FROM combo_videos ORDER BY datemade DESC LIMIT 10";
```

For each rows returned, you can check the "tableName" parameter in order to know where it comes from.

Any reason, why you have two tables that looks so similar, you may want to consider merging them and add a column to distinguish from "combo_videos" or "our_videos".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, haven't tried yet but I get the idea. Still not sure why I got -1 on question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` and add the table to each subquery:

```
SELECT 'our_videos' as which, id, title, url, description, champion, video_length, datemade
FROM our_videos
UNION ALL
SELECT 'combo_videos' as which, id, title, url, description, champion, video_length, datemade
FROM combo_videos
ORDER BY datemade DESC
LIMIT 10;
```